# Why isn't document.evaluate working?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xpath, firefox-addon, document.evaluate

I am using this in a Firefox extension and can't get it to work.

```
var allLinks = document.evaluate(
                        '//a[@href]', 
                        window.document, 
                        null, 
                        XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
                        null);
window.alert(allLinks);
```

This alerts `[object XPathResult]`. However the following always returns `0`. (And there are certainly links on the page).

```
window.alert(allLinks.snapshotLength);
```

Comment: Maybe try `someXMLDoc.evaluate()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.

```
        var allLinks = top.document.getElementById("content").selectedBrowser.contentDocument.evaluate(
                            treeView.model[0].xpath, 
                            top.document.getElementById("content").selectedBrowser.contentDocument, 
                            null, 
                            XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, 
                            null);
```

Comment: Probably it was searching in `document` which is the document of the browser itself (i.e. the main Firefox window, `browser.xul`) not the webpage you were trying to search.

Comment: By the way you can use `gBrowser` instead of `top.document.getElementById('content')`.

Answer (score 1):

If it's firefox specific and I assume you only use new versions.. can't you use querySelectorAll?

```
document.querySelectorAll('a[href]')
```

Also - are you doing it when the DOM has fully loaded? bind it to `DOMContentLoaded` or something.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn, false);
```

**EDIT: Your xpath works for me**. Did it in the console on an existing, loaded page. Pretty sure you're querying before anything exists.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that you don't want to hear - "works for me".

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/RxmTR/) (alerts 3 for me).

What browser and what version are you testing this on?

Comment: It's within a Firefox extension in 3.6.